# returning from a recursive void method doesn't exit the recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, return

I am not used to writing recursive but never had a similar issue before.

In C# I have a recursive method that has a clear base case: when all sets of colors are replaced exit and add that one to the final result. Here is my code

```
private void ColorCanBeReplacedRecursively(
    IList<IGrouping<string, Element>> userColorBag,
    IList<IGrouping<string, Element>> setColorBag)
{
    if (setColorBag.Count == 0) // if all color groups are replaced
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var setColor in setColorBag)
    {
        var futureSetColorBag = new List<IGrouping<string, Element>>();
        futureSetColorBag.AddRange(setColorBag);

        for (var i = 0; i < userColorBag.Count; i++)
        {
            var futureUserColorBag = new List<IGrouping<string, Element>>();
            futureUserColorBag.AddRange(userColorBag);

            var userHasAllPieces = HasUserAllSetPiecesInSpecificColor(userColorBag[i], setColor);
            if (userHasAllPieces)
            {
                futureUserColorBag.RemoveAll(u => u.Key.Equals(userColorBag[i].Key));
                futureSetColorBag.RemoveAll(s => s.Key.Equals(setColor.Key));

                ColorCanBeReplacedRecursively(futureUserColorBag, futureSetColorBag);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and here is how I call the recursive method for the first

```
    foreach (var set in caseSets)
    {          
        ColorCanBeReplacedRecursively(userGroupBy, setGroupBy);
        _expandedSets.Add(set);
    }
```

After some recursion the count of futureSetColorBag becomes 0, it even enters the if(count==0) but the problem is the return doesn't exit the recursive method entirely. It goes back in the loop and setColorBag finds some items to iterate one again! What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to debug your code. You need to set a breakpoint and step through the relevant code line by line to see exactly what it does and doesn't do. You can then identify exactly how and where the code doesn't behave as you expect. If you find that but still need help then you need to provide us with the information you discovered while debugging.

Comment: Add a Boolean return value to the function. If you want the recursion to stop, then return true, else return false. At every place where you call the function check the return value. And if it is true, then return true at that place as well

Comment: @jmcilhinney I did debug it of course. The futureSetColor count becomes 0 after some recursion, which is completely correct. It will even enter the if condition here         if (setColorBag.Count == 0) // if all color groups are replaced
        {
            return;
        } 
but when it does return, it returns to the inner loop again.

Comment: It sounds like the issue is not that the method doesn't implement your logic but that your logic is flawed. You should test your algorithm manually and see whether it actually works. I suspect that what happened was that you wrote without a proper algorithm in place to begin with. That would be a mistake.

Comment: @NineBerry I will give it a try, but I guess even if I write "return true" it doesn't exit the recursion.

Comment: There's something wrong with your logic after the `var userHasAllPieces =` and before the recursion. You haven't given us sample data that can show us the problem you're facing. There is no way we can answer your question without it. Jmclhinney is right - you need to debug your code.

Comment: @NineBerry thanks, it actually worked. It returns to recursive method, and sets back those values again to two lists. But eventually stops.

Comment: @Shilan - It's not a great solution. The recursion should stop naturally when your algorithm is correct. Now you have two algorithms - your computation and the bool you're passing around - and you've significantly increased the chances that your computation is buggy. I'd avoid the `bool` approach as much as I could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` only returns from the current call. It will return back to the parent call, which is still in the loop. Returning removes only the topmost call frame from the call stack. All other call frames are unaffected. That's how recursion works :)

If you want to unwind your complete stack, you have to return something from your method (such as a boolean) and then use this return value at the call-site to decide if you want to return too (and then return from the calling caller, return from the calling calling caller, and so on).

Something like this (pseudo code):

```
boolean Recurse(object param)
{
  if (abort)
  {
    return true;
  }

  foreach (var item in items)
  {
    if (Recurse(param))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: It is correct and it removes only the last call from the stack. but when you say "at the call site" you mean right before I call the recursive method again in inner loop?

Comment: @Shilan find answer updated with pseudo-code

Comment: This is certainly one way to stop recursion, but it's not the most common. Recursion like the OP's usually ends because all of the leaves of the execution tree run to exhaustion. The OP's code doesn't look like this happens. The problem isn't in his method of recursing - it's in the fact that in some branches he's not removing all of the elements.

Comment: @knittl thanks it worked. When I was debugging it, it returns all the calls I had made from before one by one. and eventually it exits the loop. However I am considering Enigmativity answer too. I am thinking should I invert my if and then I can exit the recursion with one return?

Comment: @Enigmativity you mean should I let all the iteration to the tree continue and in the end remove those leafs that are not the answer?

Comment: @Shilan it depends on what your method is supposed to do, there is no general answer :) But if you want to unwind your stack, you have to return at each level of the recursion back to the very first call.

Comment: @Shilan - If you code your algorithm correctly then you don't need these bools. The problem is in your algorithm. Fix that and it'll work fine.